# Passing variable to Styled Component to add additional styles if true

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a boolean property which currently resolves to `true` - however, when I add the following to my Styled Component, the desired styles are never added. I'm fairly sure it's a syntax issue as even if I set `shouldIndentLabel` in this component, the styles are never rendered?

```
const StyledText = styled.p`
  font-weight: 300px;
  display: inline-block;

  ${({ shouldIndentLabel }) =>
    shouldIndentLabel &&
    css`
      margin-left: 30px;
    `}
`;
```

Comment: Can you share the use of the `StyledText` component in your JSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part - I totally forgot to actually pass `StyledText` the `shouldIndentLabel` prop! My bad for not including the JSX in the original question!

```
<StyledContainer>
   <StyledText shouldIndentLabel={shouldIndentLabel}
</StyledContainer>
```